# Directing ng serve to run app on a remote computer

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, azure-active-directory, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server

Using the following code to validate a user via AAD.

```
import { Injectable, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';    
import { MessageService } from '../messages/message.service';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Idle } from '@ng-idle/core';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  config = {
    auth: {
      clientId: "********-8b39-406c-9336-13fe64e53c13", 
      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/********-13e9-4a35-b0de-b76c438a89ba", 
      redirectUri: "/", //defaults to application start page
      postLogoutRedirectUri: "/",
    },
  };
  currentUser: string;
  redirectUrl: string;

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService, private dataService: DataService, 
    private router: Router, private idle: Idle) {  }

  azureLogin() {
    const loginRequest = {scopes: []}
    const myMsal = new PublicClientApplication(this.config);
    return myMsal.loginPopup(loginRequest)
      .then((loginResponse)=> {
          let userName=loginResponse.account.username;
          sessionStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify({ token: loginResponse.accessToken}));
      });
  }
```

I cannot set up a *localhost* callback URI in Azure. Is there a way to have **ng serve** use a remote (named) server for testing?